# AJAX is returning 'undefined' Despite me knowing that the variable is tries to return isn't empty

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, undefined

I have a simple php code, which retrieves info from a database, and stores it in a multi dimensional array:

```
<?php
        //Fetches the mediainfo entries to populate the webpage, up to as many are in the DB.
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        $db = new mysqli("localhost","root","pass", "Media");
        if($db->connect_errno > 0){
            echo "ERROR";
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
            }

            $data_array=array();
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM mediainfo;";
        //  echo $sql;
            $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
            if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                $row=mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                mysqli_close($db);
                    for($i = 0; $i < count($row);$i++){

                        $data_array[$i][0] = $row[$i]['ID'];
                        $data_array[$i][1] = $row[$i]['IMGPATH'];
                        $data_array[$i][2] = $row[$i]['TITLE'];
                        $data_array[$i][3] = $row[$i]['RATING'];
                        $data_array[$i][4] = $row[$i]['POSITION'];


                    }
                    //echo $data_array[0][0];
                    return $data_array;


            if(!empty($data_array))
            {
                $data_array[0][0] = "ERROR";
            return $data_array;
            }
            else{
                $data_array[0][0] = "ERROR";
                return $data_array;
            }
            }
            else{
                $error[0][0] = "error";
                return $error;

            }


            //$JSONString = json_encode($data_array);
        //  return $data_array;

?>
```

Ignore the redundant array fillings, that was just me testing values.

The js is:

```
function loadMedia(){   
    console.log("please work");
      $.post("getMedia.php",
{


    success: function(data){
            console.log(data[0][0]);

    }})
    }
```

I'm just trying to print the first element of the first row, to see if it exists. Currently it simply prints 'undefined'. If anyone could provide any insight it would be greatly appreciated.

I'd just like to stress that I DO know that the array is full when I return it.
Thanks

**Update**
So following some quick responses(thanks) I've tried the following:

```
                if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                $row=mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                mysqli_close($db);
                    $JSONString = json_encode($row);
                    return $JSONString;
```

and:

```
<script>
    function loadMedia(){   
    console.log("please work");
      $.post("getMedia.php",
{
    success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
    }})
    }
</script>
```

Unfortunately it has the same result.

**Second update**
So I've added header('Content-type:  application/json.');, and upon explicitly calling the php file with a button, a download is launched for the JSON string. Progress!
 The php won't run automatically from my AJAX call though. Or rather, it still returns undefined.

Comment: Do `console.log(data)` and see what the server returns. (You will definitely have to return JSON and you need to parse that JSON on the client)

Comment: Or just look in the browser console and see what the response content is for the HTTP request.

Comment: Hi, could you expand on viewing the response content for the http request? I'm not sure what I'd be looking for. Thanks!

Comment: you would be looking for the json, of course. I would like to stress that the array being full has nothing to do with whether or not data[0][0] is defined. you need to provide a sample of the data php is returning to us. Is it is I don't see where you're outputting json from php.

Comment: `return` will not echo the Json! so unless you are hiding, that this lives in a function and is echoes somewhere else you need to change to `echo $JSONString;`

Comment: Okay, so even calling a test php file, which simply echoes a string is returning undefined. Clearly I'm doing something very wrong in the JS

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I simply changed from using $.post, to $.ajax format, and it worked. Very frustrating, and I don't have the understanding of why that worked.
If you're a fellow newbie running into a similar problem, here's one more solution to try!
Thanks for all the responses guys.